# angularjs controller function as attribute

Tags: angularjs

I am looking to use a controller function as an element attribute like so:

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ng-controller='myController as ctrl'>
    <div {{ ctrl.choose_attribute() }}></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `choose_attribute` function will return a string that matches one of many directives. However, my rendered html looks like this:

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ng-controller='myController as ctrl'>
    <div }}='' ctrl.choose_attribute()='' {{=''></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Am I approaching this the wrong way, or is there some trick to getting the return value to show up as an attribute?

**Edit:**
It seems my choice of the word "attribute" was not that great, so here is an example directive that I am looking to create:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', function() {
  this.choose_attribute = function () {
    if (DataService.some_value == 'blah') {
      return 'content1';
    } else {
      return 'content2';
    }
  };
})
.directive('content1', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div>some content</div>'
  };
})
.directive('content2', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div>some other content</div>'
  };
});
```

Comment: Why not use a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)? They can do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expressions will not be evaluated when placed as attribute names.

Will be evaluated: `<div class="{{value}}">Text</div>`

Will **not** be evaluated: `<div {{value}}>Text</div>`

What you need is a directive that takes a directive to add, adds it as an attribute to the element then compiles it.

Here is an example:

```
app.directive('addDirective', function($parse, $compile) {

  return {
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs) {

      var directiveGetter = $parse(tAttrs.addDirective);

      return function postLink(scope, element) {

        element.removeAttr('add-directive');

        var directive = directiveGetter(scope);
        element.attr(directive, '');

        $compile(element)(scope);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Usage:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
  <div add-directive="ctrl.choose_attribute()"></div>
  <div add-directive="ctrl.attribute"></div>
</body>
```

And JS:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {

  this.choose_attribute = function() {
    return 'content1';
  };

  this.attribute = 'content2';
});


app.directive('content1', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div>some content</div>'
  };
});

app.directive('content2', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div>some other content</div>'
  };
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Kqdtb4wDYha9OebtVkEl?p=preview